# Setting IP with a c# tool

Tags: c#, dynamic, ip

I'm a c# newby who want to learn more about programming. So I started with a simple tool, wich can set the address of a choosen network adapter to static or dynamic (like the Windows TCP/IP Properties. I set the tool's design exactly like the TCP/IP Properties).
Setting a static IP address to the network adapter works pretty good.
But when I disconnet the Computer form the network and then set the network adapter's IP to dynamic (Obtain an IP address automatically"), it won't set the Windows IP Propertie to dynamic. I'm totaly lost with this problem, I have no idea how to solve it.
I understand that I only get an IP address automatically, when I'm connected to a network (where a router or a DHCP server is enabled). 
But when I disconnect the computer form the network, an I set the IP Properties to dynamic with the the Windows TCP/IP Properties, it works well. What is worng in my code?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Below the code I'm using:

```
    public void setDHCPMode()
    {
        ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
        ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();

        foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
        {
            if (!(bool)mo["ipEnabled"])
                continue;

            try
            {
                string desc = (string)(mo["Description"]);

                if (desc == NICcomboBox.Text)
                {
                    ManagementBaseObject newDNS = mo.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder");
                    newDNS["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = null;
                    ManagementBaseObject enableDHCP = mo.InvokeMethod("EnableDHCP", null, null);
                    ManagementBaseObject setDNS = mo.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", newDNS, null);
                }

                toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "DHCP set";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to set DHCP : " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to learn more about programming, I recommend trying something that can teach you more about programming and less about Windows management classes.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It looks like the WMI dosn't work correctly. It's impossible to set the TCP/IP Properties to DHCP, while the cable is unplugged for the specific NIC.

I solved it, through setting DHCP mode in the regestry. Now it works perfectly.